# How can LDA classification accuracy be higher when using fewer linear discriminants?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

I'm trying to reduce a dataset with [LDA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.fit_transform). I expect that on reduced dataset (i.e. with fewer linear discriminants retained) I will have less classification accuracy. However, depending on the random seed, sometimes the reduced version is giving me higher accuracy.

```
# N=1000, p=50, 10 out of 50 are informative, 20 classes
X, y = make_classification(1000, 50, n_informative=10, n_classes=20)
X1, X2, y1, y2 = train_test_split(X, y)

lda = LDA()
lda.fit(X1, y1)
predicted = lda.predict(X2)
full_accuracy = accuracy_score(y2, predicted)

reduction = LDA(n_components=5)
X1red = reduction.fit_transform(X1, y1)
X2red = reduction.transform(X2)

lda.fit(X1red, y1)
predicted = lda.predict(X2red)
reduced_accuracy = accuracy_score(predicted, y2)

print full_accuracy, reduced_accuracy, reduced_accuracy/full_accuracy
# prints 0.132 0.16 1.21212121212
```

Do you know why after dimensionality reduction I have higher accuracy?

Comment: How do you measure the accuracy? On the same data as used for estimation? On a holdout sample? By croo validation?  The answer will depend on method so you must tell us!

Comment: You can see it in the code. I use another dataset to measure accuracy.

Comment: Then the reason will be differences between the datasets, the estimation was maybe overfitted building on features of the estimation dataset which do not generalize well to otherc datasets.

Comment: This happens because you are using a parsimonious model.